# How can I return a string to the operating system in my C code?

Tags: c, string, return

I am a C beginner and this is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 'sss';
}
```

That will show an error. So how can I return a string in C code?

Comment: `main` must return an `int`, no ifs, ands, or buts.  What exactly do you expect to happen to this string? (Though the "string" is really a character constant since it uses `'` delimiters instead of `"`)

Comment: An error? Copy the error message exactly. What, precisely, did you expect to happen?

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after the return statement; that is likely to be the error.  Returning `'sss'` from `main` will technically work (since it is an `int`), but it is definitely not what is desired.

Comment: This question needs to be clarified, many answers here assume that you're asking about: "How do I return a string to the operating system in C?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning C string from a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496313/returning-c-string-from-a-function)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are looking to return a string from a function (other than `main`), you should do something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * getString();

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printf("%s\n", getString());
    return 0;
}

const char * getString()
{
    const char *x = "abcstring";
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Careful, string literals are const - but the compiler doesn't always know this!

Comment: @Martin Beckett, how about add `const` before the declaration? Such as `const char *`.

Comment: @MartinBeckett, What do you mean by *"but the compiler doesn't always know this"*?

Comment: @Pacerier there are no rules (AFAIK) about what happens to the memory occupied by the string when that function exits. It may depending on your architecture be in read only program segment or in data memory. So even if it "works" don't rely on it.

Comment: @MartinBeckett, Are you saying that when we read the string (the line `printf("%s\n", getString());`), we may actually get rubbish data?

Comment: Thanks!!, this help me!

Answer (score 4):

The magic is in the key word `static` which preserves the memory content of the string even after the function ends. (You can consider it like extending the scope of the variable.)

This code takes one character each time, then concatenates them in a string and saves it into a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

char* strbsmallah ()
{
  static char input[50];
  char position = 0, letter;
  scanf("%c", &letter);
  while (letter != '~') { // Press '~' to end your text
    input[position] = letter;
    ++position;
    scanf("%c", &letter);
  }
  input[position] = '\0';
  char *y;
  y = (char*) &input;
  //printf("%s\n ", y);
  return y;
}

int main() {
  printf("\n");
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("bsmallah.txt", "w+");
  fprintf(fp, strbsmallah());

  while (!_kbhit())
    ;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But it will overwrite memory if typing more than 50 characters(?).

Comment: What is _kbhit()? Is it specific to a particular platform (say, Windows)?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a way similar to `scanf`. In other words:

```
void foo(char **value_to_return) {
    *value_to_return = malloc(256); // Store 256 characters
    strcpy(*value_to_return, "deposited string");
}

int main() {
    char *deposit;
    foo(&deposit);
    printf("%s", deposit);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no way to do that.

You could add something to the end of your C program like:

```
int main()
{
    int err = 0; // 0 is "success" is most C programs
    printf("Hello, World!!\n");

    switch( err )
    {
      case 0:
        printf("Program shutdown successfully!\n");
        break;
      case 1:
        printf("We had an issue somewhere. Please fix your input data\n");
        break;
      //case 2, 3, etc...
    };

   return err;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't return a string. Applications exit with an integer exit code.

Conventionally, exiting with a return of 0 will always show that your application exited without error / completed. You return an integer other than 0 to show that your application exited abnormally.

You could throw an exception and handle it with a logging method higher in the call stack, or you could just return something other than 0 and make sure you had it documented in your release notes as to what each error integer means.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use environment variables for that. Not sure though.

Comment: Perhaps find out and [update your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4929444/edit) (not here in comments)?