# Is it legal to return a string using `const char *` like this?

Tags: c++, c, memory, char

Here  is the code changed a bit from this thread:[How to return a string in my C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929329/how-to-return-a-string-in-my-c-code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char * getString();
int main()
{
 printf("hello world\n");
 printf("%s\n", getString());
 printf("%s\n", getString2());
 return 0;

}

const char * getString()
{
 const char *x = "abcstring";
 return x;
}

const char * getString2()
{
 return "abcstring";
}
```

This looks a bit confusing to me because the memory space which `x` points to, `"abcstring"`, in `getString` seems to be on stack instead of on heap. Therefore, the allocated memory for `x` may be freed at the end of `getString`. If so, will `printf("%s\n", getString());` fail?

And What about `printf("%s\n", getString2());`?

Comment: "the x variable in getString seems to be on stack instead of on heap". The `x` variable is an automatic variable (not necessarily on the stack BTW) but not what it is pointing to.

Comment: String constants are never on the stack.  If they were, it would imply that the runtime environment was dynamically copying them there.  It doesn't.  They're in static storage.

Comment: Returning string literals is safe. Calling the `getString2` function without having first declared its prototype is *not* safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the allocated memory for x may be freed at the end of getString

Yes, but only for `x`, [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) won't.

> String literals have **static storage duration**, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program.

According to the C++ stardard, $2.13.5/8 String literals [lex.string] (bold by me)

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array
>   of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below,
>   and has **static storage duration** (3.7).

And for C [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal),

> Then (at stage 7), a terminating null character is added to each
>   string literal, and then each literal initializes an unnamed array
>   with **static storage duration** and length just enough to contain the
>   contents of the string literal plus one the null terminator.

Comment: May be worth adding the `C` [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) as well, since the question is tagged as both `C++` and `C`.

Comment: @dxiv Didn't notice that. Thanks.