# "Life-time" of a string literal in C

Tags: c, function, local-variables, string-literals, lifetime

Wouldn't the pointer returned by the following function be inaccessible?

```
char *foo(int rc)
{
    switch (rc)
    {
        case 1:

            return("one");

        case 2:

            return("two");

        default:

            return("whatever");
    }
}
```

So the lifetime of a local variable in C/C++ is practically only within the function, right? Which means, after `char* foo(int)` terminates, the pointer it returns no longer means anything, right?

I'm a bit confused about the lifetime of a local variable. What is a good clarification?

Comment: The only "var" you have in your function is the parameter `int rc`. Its lifetime ends at each one of the `return`-s.  The pointers you are returning are to string literals. String literals have static storage duration: their lifetime is at least as long as that of the program.

Comment: What if it's not String literal but other kinds of literal, such as: int *foo () { return &(2); // or // int n = 2; // return &n; }

Comment: Check the Edit in my answer which addresses your query.Note, that you should have posted this as an comment and not an answer.Queries, doubts etc should be posted in comments, only answers should be posted under answers.

Comment: What you mean by "valid"? Your code will sure works (and you can see it if try to compile), however i can't imagine a use for a function that returns a constant string.

Comment: @PedroAlves Why not? Methods allow abstraction; what if in the future the string will be read from a translation resource, but internationalization support isn't needed for V1 (or V0.5) of a product?

Comment: @dlev Sure, but this method isn't reading the string from anywhere, it just returns a constant string. This question can be replaced by "Can a method return a constant string?" or "How can i return a constant string from a method?".

Comment: @PedroAlves *"Your code will sure works (and you can see it if try to compile),"* That does not follow. Many (most? Essentially every?) c compiler will consume illegal code, and often emit code that appears to work. But try it in *another* compiler (or even a different version of the same compiler) and it may fall over.

Comment: @PedroAlves, a function that returns a single constant string might be of limited use, but how about one that returns any one of a number of constant strings depending on the input or object state? A simple example would be a function to convert an enumeration into its string representation.

Comment: You've never seen the `strerror` function, evidently.

Comment: You may want use a `char const * const foo()` as it match perfectly the type of your pointer.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Yes, the lifetime of a local variable is within the scope(`{`,`}`) in which it is created.

Local variables have automatic or local storage. *Automatic* because they are automatically destroyed once the scope within which they are created ends.

However, What you have here is a string literal, which is allocated in an implementation-defined read-only memory. String literals are different from local variables and they remain alive throughout the program lifetime. They have *static duration* <sup>[Ref 1]</sup> lifetime.

**A word of caution!**

However, note that any attempt to modify the contents of a string literal is an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB). User programs are not allowed to modify the contents of a string literal.
Hence, it is always encouraged to use a `const` while declaring a string literal.

```
const char*p = "string";
```

instead of,

```
char*p = "string";
```

In fact, in C++ it is deprecated to declare a string literal without the `const` though not in C. However, declaring a string literal with a `const` gives you the advantage that compilers would usually give you a warning in case you attempt to modify the string literal in the second case.

**[Sample program](http://ideone.com/7ZdBk):**

```
#include<string.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    char *str1 = "string Literal"; 
    const char *str2 = "string Literal"; 
    char source[]="Sample string"; 
 
    strcpy(str1,source);    // No warning or error just Undefined Behavior 
    strcpy(str2,source);    // Compiler issues a warning 
 
    return 0; 
}
```

**Output:**

> cc1: warnings being treated as errors 
> prog.c: In function ‘main’: 
> prog.c:9: error: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Notice the compiler warns for the second case, but not for the first.

---

To answer the question being asked by a couple of users here:

**What is the deal with integral literals?**

In other words, is the following code valid?

```
int *foo()
{
    return &(2);
}
```

The answer is, no this code is not valid. It is ill-formed and will give a compiler error.

Something like:

```
prog.c:3: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

String literals are l-values, i.e: You can take the address of a string literal, but cannot change its contents.
However, any other literals (`int`, `float`, `char`, etc.) are r-values (the C standard uses the term *the value of an expression* for these) and their address cannot be taken at all.

---

<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>**C99 standard 6.4.5/5 "String Literals - Semantics":**

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. **The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence**. For character string literals, the array elements have type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence; for wide string literals, the array elements have type wchar_t, and are initialized with the sequence of wide characters...
>
> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: What if the user is returning some thing like this. char *a=&"abc"; return a;  Will this not be valid?

Comment: @Ashwin: The type of the string literal is `char (*)[4]`. This is because, type of *"abc"* is `char[4]` and pointer to an array of 4 characters is declared as `char (*)[4]`, So If you need to take address of it, You need to do it as `char (*a)[4] = &"abc";` and Yes, it is valid.

Comment: @Als "abc" is `char[4]`. (Because of the `'\0'`)

Comment: @asaelr: Indeed! a typo, Fixed it, Thanks.

Comment: @Ashwin: No, it would still be perfectly valid because you're returning the *value* of `a`, not the address of `a`...aside from the fact that you have your types wrong. `&"abc"` has type `char (*)[4]` and is not compatible with `char *`. Ditch the `&`.

Comment: @R.. : okay so you are telling that the value lives along but the address is erased? But where is the value stored.

Comment: Maybe it would also be a good idea to warn that `char const s[] = "text";` does *not* make `s` a character literal, and therefore `s` *will* be destroyed at the end of the scope, so any surviving pointers to it will dangle.

Comment: @celtschk: I would love to, but the Q is specifically about string literals So I would stick to the topic at hand.However, For ones interested my answer here, [What is the difference between char a\[\] = “string” and char *p = “string”?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9631091/452307) should be rather helpful.

Comment: What if it's not a string literal, but an integer (or any other primitive) literal? That is, if the function signature is changed to return an `int * foo(...)`, and inside the function it returns something like `return &(2);`?

Comment: @user1064918: Check the Edit in the answer which addresses your query.

Comment: what if i reassign `p="newstring"`? i see the *p has new address with new value, but is there any consequence of it?

Answer (score 81):

It's valid. String literals have static storage duration, so the pointer is not dangling.

For C, that is mandated in section 6.4.5, paragraph 6:

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. The multibyte character sequence is then used **to initialize an array of static storage duration** and length just sufficient to contain the sequence.

And for C++ in section 2.14.5, paragraphs 8-11:

> 8 Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array of n `const char`”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).
>
> 9 A string literal that begins with u, such as `u"asdf"`, is a `char16_t` string literal. A `char16_t` string literal has type “array of n `const char16_t`”, where n is the size of the string as defined below; it has static storage duration and is initialized with the given characters. A single c-char may produce more than one `char16_t` character in the form of surrogate pairs.
>
> 10 A string literal that begins with U, such as `U"asdf"`, is a `char32_t` string literal. A `char32_t` string literal has type “array of n `const char32_t`”, where n is the size of the string as defined below; it has static storage duration and is initialized with the given characters.
>
> 11 A string literal that begins with L, such as `L"asdf"`, is a wide string literal. A wide string literal has type “array of n `const wchar_t`”, where n is the size of the string as defined below; it has static storage duration and is initialized with the given characters.

Comment: FYI: this answer was merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470959/can-we-return-string-literal-in-c

Answer (score 14):

String literals are valid for the whole program (and are not allocated not the stack), so it will be valid.

Also, string literals are read-only, so (for good style) maybe you should change `foo` to `const char *foo(int)`

Comment: What if the user is returning some thing like this. char *a=&"abc"; return a;  Will this not be valid?

Comment: `&"abc"` is not `char*`. it's an address of array, and its type is `char(*)[4]`. However, either `return &"abc";` and `char *a="abc";return a;` are valid.

Comment: @asaelr: Actually, it is more than just for sake of *for a good style*, check my answer for the details.

Comment: @Als Well, if he writes the whole program, he can avoid changing the string without writing `const`, and it will be completely legal, but it still bad style.

Comment: if it's valid for the whole program, why we need to malloc it?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is valid code, see case 1 below. You can safely return C strings from a function in at least these ways:

- `const char*` to a string literal. It can't be modified and must not be freed by caller. It is rarely useful for the purpose of returning a default value, because of the freeing problem described below. It might make sense if you actually need to pass a function pointer somewhere, so you need a function returning a string..
- `char*` or `const char*` to a static char buffer. It must not be freed by the caller. It can be modified (either by the caller if not const, or by the function returning it), but a function returning this can't (easily) have multiple buffers, so it is not (easily) threadsafe, and the caller may need to copy the returned value before calling the function again.
- `char*` to a buffer allocated with `malloc`. It can be modified, but it must usually be explicitly freed by the caller and has the heap allocation overhead. `strdup` is of this type.
- `const char*` or `char*` to a buffer, which was passed as an argument to the function (the returned pointer does not need to point to the first element of argument buffer). It leaves responsibility of buffer/memory management to the caller. Many standard string functions are of this type.

One problem is, mixing these in one function can get complicated. The caller needs to know how it should handle the returned pointer, how long it is valid, and if caller should free it, and there's no (nice) way of determining that at runtime. So you can't, for example, have a function, which sometimes returns a pointer to a heap-allocated buffer which caller needs to `free`, and sometimes a pointer to a default value from string literal, which caller must *not* `free`.

Comment: FYI: this answer was merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470959/can-we-return-string-literal-in-c

Answer (score 6):

Good question.  In general, you would be right, but your example is the exception.  The compiler statically allocates global memory for a string literal.  Therefore, the address returned by your function is valid.

That this is so is a rather convenient feature of C, isn't it?  It allows a function to return a precomposed message without forcing the programmer to worry about the memory in which the message is stored.

See also @asaelr's correct observation re `const`.

Comment: :What if the user is returning some thing like this. char *a=&"abc"; return a;  Will this not be valid?

Comment: Right.  Actually, one can just write `const char *a = "abc";`, omitting the `&`.  The reason is that a double-quoted string resolves to the address of its initial character.

Answer (score 3):

Local variables are only valid within the scope they're declared, however you don't declare any local variables in that function.

It's perfectly valid to return a pointer to a string literal from a function, as a string literal exists throughout the entire execution of the program, just as a `static` or a global variable would.

If you're worrying about what you're doing might be invalid undefined, you should turn up your compiler warnings to see if there is in fact anything you're doing wrong.

Comment: What if the user is returning some thing like this. char *a=&"abc"; return a;  Will this not be valid?

Comment: @Ashwin: `&"abc"` isn't of type `char*`, however both `"abc"` and `&"abc"` are valid throughout the whole execution of the program.

Answer (score 2):

`str` will never be a dangling pointer, because *it points to a static address* where string literals resides.

It will be mostly *read-only* and *global* to the program when it will be loaded.

Even if you try to free or modify, it will throw a *[segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)* **on platforms with memory protection**.

Comment: FYI: this answer was merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470959/can-we-return-string-literal-in-c

Comment: if it will never be dangling, do i need to malloc it? No?

Answer (score 0):

A local variable is allocated on the stack. After the function finishes, the variable goes out of scope and is no longer accessible in the code. However, if you have a global (or simply - not yet out of scope) pointer that you assigned to point to that variable, it will point to the place in the stack where that variable was. It could be a value used by another function, or a meaningless value.

Comment: What if the user is returning some thing like this. char *a=&"abc"; return a;  Will this not be valid?

Answer (score -1):

In the above example shown by you, you are actually returning the allocated pointers to whatever function that calls the above. So it would not become a local pointer. And moreover, for the pointers that are needed to be returned, memory is allocated in the global segment.