# Does this code cause memory leaks

Tags: c, pointers, memory, variable-assignment, memory-leaks

```
int main()
{
    char* str;

    str = "string one";
    str = "string two";
    str = func();
    str = "string four";
    return 0;
}

char* func()
{
    char* tmp;

    tmp = "string three";
    return tmp;
}
```

I know  `str = "string one";`  allocates memory for this string and assigns the address of that memory to  `str` . by right the same thing should happen when  `str = "string two";`   and  `str = func();`  and  `str = "string four";`  are executed, now I'm wondering how memory is handled in this situation. Does memory allocated to those strings release when new assignment happens or it's a form of memory leak?

Comment: Just for caution, do yourself the favor and take the habit to assign string literals only to variables that are declared `char const*`. String literals are not modifiable, so declaring them as you do may only bring you trouble.

Comment: the difference: for str = "text"; memory is allocacated by the LINKER, with str = malloc(); YOU allocate the memory and are supposed to free(); the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no memory leaks in your code since it's not allocating anything. You only have string literals on the right-hand side of every assignment, and those don't need to be (and can't be) deallocated.

See ["life-time" of string literal in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970295/life-time-of-string-literal-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

No need to `free` this type of assignment. because they are allocated in `stack`(temp) memory only. If you have allocate memory using `malloc`(they are allocated in `heap`), you have to `free`