# Can we return string literal in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dangling-pointer

Is this code valid?

```
const char* foo() {
  return "Hello World";
}
```

That is, return "Hello World" from a C function.

```
const char* str = foo();
```

Will str be a dangling pointer?

PS: The above function is abstracted from some real code. I see someone write code that returns a string literal directly.