# When will C free memory of struct

Tags: c, memory-management, dll, struct, memory-leaks

I've got a question to C structs and datatypes. I have a struct called `test`:

```
struct test
{
    char* c;
    char* c2;
};
```

And I am returning this struct from a function:

```
struct test a()
{
    struct test t = { "yeah!", "string" };
    return t;
}
```

My question is whether the memory for the struct is freed automatically or if I have to do this manually via `free()`.

[update [from comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256792/when-will-c-free-memory-of-struct#comment62040729_37256810):]

The function a is in a DLL and I want to use the struct in the main program.

Comment: Good place to understand pointers: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/

Comment: _Automatically_. Done.

Comment: what do you understand by "freed"?

Comment: As the struct gets copied up to the caller, the more interesting question is: "How long will the string literals referenced by the structure's members stay valid?"

Comment: you can do it a bit easier. just `return (struct test) {"yeah!", "string"};`

Comment: Oh okay didn't notice, thanks.

Comment: Related (as for what the members point to): http://stackoverflow.com/q/9970295/694576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL/DR Version:** You do not need to manually `free` anything; you can treat this struct instance the way you would treat any scalar variable.

**Slightly Longer Version:** The struct instance `t` has *automatic storage duration*, meaning its lifetime extends over the lifetime of the `a` function; once `a` exits, any memory allocated for `t` is released.  A *copy* of the contents of `t` is returned to the caller.

As for those contents...

`c` and `c2` are pointing to *string literals*; string literals are allocated such that their lifetime extends over the entire program's execution.  So the pointer values in `c` and `c2` will be valid after `t` is returned from `a`; indeed, those pointer values will be valid over the lifetime of the program.

You should only have to call `free` on something that was allocated via `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.

Answer (score 5):

You should only `free` something which you `malloc`ed (or used another similar function) first. Since nothing was `malloc`ed, nothing should be `free`d.

Comment: But how long can I use the struct then? The function `a` is in a DLL and I want to use the struct in the main program. How does the compiler know when to delete the struct?

Comment: Compiler uses memcopy to copy struct when you do `return t`
Unfortunately DLL is doing a terrible job of using string literals ("yeah!", "string") to return data. Life-time of these is usually as long as the DLL is in memory on most systems so memory returned is mostly unusable. Better solution is to allocate on heap, do string copy & then return struct. Have caller do the free once it is done with the struct.

Comment: @Chintan there is no such guarantee. A struct return value might as well be in registers or so.

Comment: @LucaSchimweg, this is why it is called `automatic` variable - compiler manages it's lifetime automatically for you.

Comment: I would very much like the downvoter to explain the reason for downvote.

Comment: Ok, thanks it seems as I can use the variable without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to free a non-dynamic allocation. Nevertheless, If you want to use the struct in an other function, you have to pass the address of the struct, and take it as a (struct *), if you don't, you will not be able to use it again.

Comment: Not true. Structs can (and in this case are) passed by value just fine.

Comment: I never deny it. So stop downvote for nothing please.