# Why might a string literal not be a string?

Tags: c, string, null, language-lawyer, string-literals

I'm struggling with this part in the C standard about string literals, especially the second part of it:

> "*In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. 80)*"
>
> ---
>
> "*80)  A string literal might not be a string (see 7.1.1), because a null character can be embedded in it by a `\0` escape sequence.*"
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §6.4.5/6, Page 51

I don't understand the explanation - "*because a null character can be embedded in it by a `\0` escape sequence.*".

---

To look at the referenced section §7.1.1., regarding the definition of a "string", it is stated:

> "*A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.*"
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §7.1.1/1, Page 132

I've thought about that the focus maybe lays on the "*can*", in a way that a string literal does not have to include/embed the null character, while a string is needed to.

But then again I´m asking myself: How is one able to use a string literal as string if it has not a string-terminating null character in it, to determine the end of the string (required for string-operating functions)?

I´m totally drawing blanks at the moment.

---

*Note*: I´m aware of that a string literal is stored in read-only memory and can´t be modified and a string is a generic term for a sequence of characters terminated by NUL, which can or can not be mutable.

Thus, my question is not: "*What is the difference between a string and a string literal?*"

My Question is:

- Why/How can a string-literal not be a string?

and, according to my concerns, so far:

- Is it true, that a string literal can have the NUL byte omitted?

---

I wanted to ask this question myself but short before posting it, I got the clue. My confusion was made because of the little misplaced wording inside of the quote.

But I decided to not delete the question´s draft as it could be useful for future readers and provide a Q&A instead.

Feel free to comment and hint.

---

Related stuff:

- [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)
- [What is the type of string literals in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-and-c)
- [Are string literals const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const)
- ["Life-time" of a string literal in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970295/life-time-of-a-string-literal-in-c/9970305#9970305)

Comment: I'd say it's a bug in the documentation -- having `char *p = "foo\0bar";` we can say `p` points to a string with length 3; `p+4` points to another string :)

Comment: @pmg Indeed.  `"foo\0bar"` is a string literal that contains ***two*** strings, thus it is not ***a*** string.  Yes, it really is that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking it.

> "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §7.1.1/1, Page 132

says that a "string" only extends up to the first null character.  Characters that may exist after the null are not part of the string.  However

> "80) A string literal might not be a string (see 7.1.1), because a null character can be embedded in it by a \0 escape sequence."

makes it clear a string literal *may* contain an embedded null.  If it does, the string literal **AS A WHOLE** is not a string -- the string is just the prefix of the string literal up to the first null

Answer (score 0):

Let´s take a look at the definition of the term "*string literal*" at the same section in C18, §6.5.1/3:

> "*A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in `"xyz"`.*"

According to that, a string literal is only consisted of the characters enclosed in quotation marks, the bare string content. It does not have an appended `\0`. The NUL byte is appended later at translation, as said at §6.5.1/6:

> "*In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. 80)*"

---

Let´s make an example:

`"foo"` is a *string literal*, but not a *string* because `"foo"` does not contain an *embedded* null character.

`"foo\0"` is a *string literal* and a *string* because the literal itself contains a null character at the end of the character sequence.

---

Note that you don´t need to explicitly insert the null character at the end of a *string literal* to change it to a *string*. As already said, it is implicitly appended during the program translation.

Means,

```
const char *s = "foo";
```

is equal to

```
const char *s = "foo\0";
```

---

I admit, that the sentence of:

> "*A string literal might not be a string (see 7.1.1), because a null character can be embedded in it by a `\0` escape sequence.*"

is a little confusing and illogical in the context. It would be better phrased:

> "*A string literal might not be a string (see 7.1.1), because a null character **might not** (OR **is not required to**) be embedded in it by a `\0` escape sequence.*"

or alternatively:

> "*A string literal might **<s>not</s>** be a string (see 7.1.1), because a null character can be embedded in it by a `\0` escape sequence.*"

---

As [@EricPostpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) pointed in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62233020/why-might-a-string-literal-not-be-a-string?noredirect=1#comment110064906_62233021), the meaning of the footnote is probably quite different.

It means that if the *string literal* contains a null character inside of it, but not at the end, as it is required for a *string*, the *string literal* is not equivalent to a *string*.

F.e.: 
The *string literal*

```
"foo\0bar"
```

is not a *string*, as it contains the first null character *embedded* inside of the *string literal*, but not at the end of it.

Comment: You have missed, or at least not made clear, an aspect. The sequence of characters defined by `"abc\0def"` is not a string because it is not terminated by its first null character. 77.11 says “A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.” That is why footnote 80 says a string literal might not be a string: A string literal might not conform to the rule that a string ends with its first null character.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ahh, that makes sense. I focused on the existence of the null character itself but not its location. Yes, then actually, the footnote makes sense. I took your input into the answer. But nonetheless, I think this footnote is not quite clear and idiot-proof, like it was well shown by this question. :-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil But it gives another question to me: Is `"abc\0\0"` by that definition a string?

Comment: `"abc\0\0"` has a character, `\0`, after its first null character, so that character sequence does not conform to the rule for what a string is.