# Is it superfluous to use the static keyword inside functions for string literals?

Tags: c

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16470975/1197719) string literals are always static. This makes me wonder whether the following functions do exactly the same:

```
static const char *foo1(void) {return "bar";}
static const char *foo2(void) {const char *bar = "bar";return bar;}
static const char *foo3(void) {static const char *bar = "bar";return bar;}
```

Is there any significant difference between `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` or not? In other words: Is using the `static` keyword superfluous when declaring string literals inside functions?

Comment: The type of strings literals in ```C``` is an array of ```char```, but in ```C++```, it is an array of ```const char```. The ```static``` in the function declaration applies to linkage, in this case internal linkage.

Comment: ...which means that this function is only visible in this translation unit. In the declaration ```static const char *bar```, the static applies to the pointer ```bar```, not what it is being assigned with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are completely equivalent. Here is GCC's output with `-O2`:

```
.LC0:
        .string "bar"
foo1:
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        ret
foo2:
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        ret
foo3:
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        ret
```

And in any case, you are not applying `static` to the string literal itself. You are declaring the *pointer* `bar` to be a local static variable. But you don't use that pointer variable for anything but copying its value to the function return value. So it can't matter whether it is `static` or not.

Comment: Hw did not ask about it.

Answer (score 2):

None of the `static` are related to the string literal.

`static const char *foox(...`

This static means something completely different. Functions will have only internal linkage.

```
static const char *bar = "bar";return bar;
```

This `static` does not have anything in common with the string literal. It affects only the variable `bar` which will have a static storage duration.