# What are the problems that could arise from setting a returned char * to a string literal that's defined within a function?

Tags: c

As an example:

```
static const char * color_to_str(enum Color color) {
    switch (color) {
       case COLOR_RED:
           return "RED";
       case COLOR_BLUE:
           return "BLUE";
       default:
           return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}

static void do_something() {
   printf("The color is %s\n", color_to_str(COLOR_RED));
}
```

Is it dangerous to be returning a pointer to these string literals? What are the issues with such approach?

Comment: Counter-question would be why you think there is an issue with this approach? String literals have a [well-specified lifetime (static duration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970295/life-time-of-a-string-literal-in-c), what other potential problems are you thinking of?

Comment: @UnholySheep, it was mainly my uncertainty that led me to ask this question.  I wanted to clear myself of that uncertainty.  I wasn't sure where in memory this is stored/it's lifetime (or whether there is something that might not make this eligible as a a "string literal"). The link you shared answered my question.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with this code. string literals are stored in the read-only data section of the binary. Returning a `char const *` is a perfectly valid code. If you had returned a `char *` however, it may trigger undefined behavior if someone tries to modify it.

Comment: It does not matter where it is stored - as it is up to implementation. The important bit is: it has a ***static storage duration*** so its lifetime is the same as the program

Comment: Yes. It does not matter where it is stored it is up to the implementation. That's what I did not mention specifically `.bss`.  It might get optimised away too.  But this is easier to grasp.