# How to transfer result gotten from a function to an array of char in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

The motive of my program is to test for the longest word in a string and return whether or not the longest word matches the expected result.

I wrote the code but my brain got stuck in the part where I'm to store the result of my function longest word on line into the char array result. How do you do this in C?

My effort:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

static int testsExecuted = 0;
static int testsFailed = 0;

char testLongestWord(char line[], char expected[]);
void longestWord(char line[]);

int main(int args, char *argv[]){
    printf("%s\n", "Testing typical cases, including punctuation\n");
    testLongestWord("the quick brown foxes jumped over the lazy dogs", "jumped");
    testLongestWord("hello world she said", "hello");
    testLongestWord("Hello\tworld\tshe\tsaid", "Hello");
    testLongestWord("HELLO, world she said", "HELLO");
    testLongestWord("hello world! she said???", "hello");
    testLongestWord("\"hello world!\", she said.", "hello");
    testLongestWord("easy as abc123", "abc123");
    testLongestWord("easy as abc,123", "easy");


    printf("\n%s\n", "Testing empty cases\n" );
    testLongestWord("", "");
    testLongestWord("!", "");
    testLongestWord(" ", "");
    testLongestWord("\t", "");
    testLongestWord("      ", "");
    testLongestWord("# $ ? % !", "");

    printf("\n%s\n", "Testing edge cases\n" );
    testLongestWord("a", "a");
    testLongestWord("abc", "abc");
    testLongestWord("abc d e f ghi", "abc");
    testLongestWord("a a b cc dd abc", "abc");
    testLongestWord("\"a a b cc dd abc.\"", "abc");


    printf("\n%s\n", "Testing apostrophes and dashes\n" );
    testLongestWord("this isn't five chars", "chars");
    testLongestWord("this should've been eight chars said the computer", "should've");
    testLongestWord("'this should've been eight chars', said the computer", "should've");
    testLongestWord("'hello world!', she said softly.", "softly");
    testLongestWord("topsy-turvy is a tenletter word", "topsy-turvy");
    testLongestWord("topsy-turvy should not be incorrectly eleven characters", "incorrectly");
    testLongestWord("---in-between-these---", "in-between-these");
    testLongestWord("---in---between---these---", "between");
    testLongestWord("here-is-an-edge-case but a muchmuchlongerword", "muchmuchlongerword");
    testLongestWord("d-o-n't-g-o-o-v-e-r-t-h-e-e-d-g-e with muchmuchlongerwords", "muchmuchlongerwords");
    testLongestWord("two=five-3 isn't three", "three");

    printf("\n%s\n", "These tests will be opposite in the C version\n");
    testLongestWord("the word antidisestablishmentarianism is very long but not as long as 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch'.", "Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch");
    testLongestWord("the word antidisestablishmentarianism is very long but not as long as 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch'.", "antidisestablishment");
    testLongestWord("Java strings may contain \0 in the interior", "interior");
    testLongestWord("C strings cannot contain \0 in the interior", "strings");

    printf("Total number of test executed:  %d\n", testsExecuted );
    printf("number of test passed:  %d\n", (testsExecuted - testsFailed));
    printf("Number of test failed: %d\n", testsFailed );

    //longestWord("Java strings may contain \0 in the interior");

}

char testLongestWord(char line[], char expected[]){
    //char result[200];
      String result = longestWords(line); //This is how it'd have been in Java
    /*longestWord(line);*/
    //strcpy(result, line);
    //char *result = longestWord(line);
    //printf("%s\n", line );
    //longestWord(&line)

    if(strcmp(result,expected)){ // function returns 0 if they are equal
        printf("passed: '%s' from '%s'\n", result, line);
    }else{
        printf("FAILED: '%s' from '%s'\n", expected, result);
        testsFailed++;
    }
    testsExecuted++;
    return 0;

}


void longestWord(char line[]){
    char longest[200];

    int pos = 0;
    int longestLength = 0;
    char current[300];
    int currentLength = 0;
    char ch;
    size_t maxPos = strlen(line);

    while(pos < maxPos){
        ch = line[pos++];
        for(pos = 0; pos < maxPos;pos++){
            ch = line[pos++];
            if((ch == '\'' || ch == '-') && (pos > 0) && isalpha(line[pos-1]) && isalpha(line[pos+1])){
                strcpy(current, &ch);
            }else if(isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch)){
                strcpy(current, &ch);
                currentLength++;
                //printf("%s\n", longest );

            }else{
                if(currentLength > longestLength){
                    strcpy(longest,current);
                    longestLength = currentLength;
                }
                //strcpy(current, "");
                currentLength =0;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Output: (This output was given in a similar code just done in Java)

```
Testing typical cases, including punctuation

Passed: 'jumped' from 'the quick brown foxes jumped over the lazy dogs'
Passed: 'hello' from 'hello world she said'
Passed: 'Hello' from 'Hello world   she said'
Passed: 'HELLO' from 'HELLO, world she said'
Passed: 'hello' from 'hello world! she said???'
Passed: 'hello' from '"hello world!", she said.'
Passed: 'abc123' from 'easy as abc123'
Passed: 'easy' from 'easy as abc,123'

Testing empty cases

Passed: '' from ''
Passed: '' from '!'
Passed: '' from ' '
Passed: '' from '   '
Passed: '' from '      '
Passed: '' from '# $ ? % !'

Testing edge cases

Passed: 'a' from 'a'
Passed: 'abc' from 'abc'
Passed: 'abc' from 'abc d e f ghi'
Passed: 'abc' from 'a a b cc dd abc'
Passed: 'abc' from '"a a b cc dd abc."'

Testing apostrophes and dashes

Passed: 'chars' from 'this isn't five chars'
Passed: 'should've' from 'this should've been eight chars said the computer'
Passed: 'should've' from ''this should've been eight chars', said the computer'
Passed: 'softly' from ''hello world!', she said softly.'
Passed: 'topsy-turvy' from 'topsy-turvy is a tenletter word'
Passed: 'incorrectly' from 'topsy-turvy should not be incorrectly eleven characters'
Passed: 'in-between-these' from '---in-between-these---'
Passed: 'between' from '---in---between---these---'
Passed: 'muchmuchlongerword' from 'here-is-an-edge-case but a muchmuchlongerword'
Passed: 'muchmuchlongerwords' from 'd-o-n't-g-o-o-v-e-r-t-h-e-e-d-g-e with muchmuchlongerwords'
Passed: 'three' from 'two=five-3 isn't three'

These tests will be opposite in the C version

Passed: 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch' from 'the word antidisestablishmentarianism is very long but not as long as 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch'.'
FAILED: 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch' instead of 'antidisestablishment' from 'the word antidisestablishmentarianism is very long but not as long as 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch'.'
Passed: 'interior' from 'Java strings may contain  in the interior'
FAILED: 'interior' instead of 'strings' from 'C strings cannot contain  in the interior'

Total number of tests executed: 34
Number of tests passed:         32
Number of tests failed:         2
```

Comment: The often (even usually) misquoted pangram is *"A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."* Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog) perpetuates the superfluity, although the proper pangram gets a mention.

Comment: Your `longestWord` function corrently does not do anything with `longest` .. you'll need to address that problem before worrying about `testLongestWord`

Comment: @WeatherVane what superfluity is perpetuated? WP has the usual version in the title, and mentions that a different version has been used too

Comment: longest? I was copying current into longest in the els statement.       (I'm still new to c from java and a little bit confused and still asking silly questions) :/ @M.M

Comment: @T-- maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798977/returning-string-from-c-function) will help

Comment: C doesn't have strings. Your `testLongestWord` function only returns a single character. To "return" a string in C, the usual idiom is for the caller to allocate and pass into the function a character array and its length. See, for example, `sprintf()`.

Comment: Yes you're copying into `longest` but then you never tell anyone else about `longest`, so the function `testLongestWord` cannot see the results of your copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had a few problems. The sense on your final `strcmp` if was reversed. The word finding logic was a bit convoluted, advancing `pos` multiple times [incorrectly], and the mechanism for returning strings (ala java) didn't work. One simplification was to split off some of the `longestWord` code into `nextWord`

I've fixed the code with some annotations [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

static int testsExecuted = 0;
static int testsFailed = 0;

char testLongestWord(char line[], char expected[]);
//void longestWord(char line[]);

int
main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", "Testing typical cases, including punctuation\n");
    testLongestWord("the quick brown foxes jumped over the lazy dogs", "jumped");
    testLongestWord("hello world she said", "hello");
    testLongestWord("Hello\tworld\tshe\tsaid", "Hello");
    testLongestWord("HELLO, world she said", "HELLO");
    testLongestWord("hello world! she said???", "hello");
    testLongestWord("\"hello world!\", she said.", "hello");
    testLongestWord("easy as abc123", "abc123");
    testLongestWord("easy as abc,123", "easy");

    printf("\n%s\n", "Testing empty cases\n");
    testLongestWord("", "");
    testLongestWord("!", "");
    testLongestWord(" ", "");
    testLongestWord("\t", "");
    testLongestWord("      ", "");
    testLongestWord("# $ ? % !", "");

    printf("\n%s\n", "Testing edge cases\n");
    testLongestWord("a", "a");
    testLongestWord("abc", "abc");
    testLongestWord("abc d e f ghi", "abc");
    testLongestWord("a a b cc dd abc", "abc");
    testLongestWord("\"a a b cc dd abc.\"", "abc");

    printf("\n%s\n", "Testing apostrophes and dashes\n");
    testLongestWord("this isn't five chars", "chars");
    testLongestWord("this should've been eight chars said the computer", "should've");
    testLongestWord("'this should've been eight chars', said the computer", "should've");
    testLongestWord("'hello world!', she said softly.", "softly");
    testLongestWord("topsy-turvy is a tenletter word", "topsy-turvy");
    testLongestWord("topsy-turvy should not be incorrectly eleven characters", "incorrectly");
    testLongestWord("---in-between-these---", "in-between-these");
    testLongestWord("---in---between---these---", "between");
    testLongestWord("here-is-an-edge-case but a muchmuchlongerword", "muchmuchlongerword");
    testLongestWord("d-o-n't-g-o-o-v-e-r-t-h-e-e-d-g-e with muchmuchlongerwords", "muchmuchlongerwords");
    testLongestWord("two=five-3 isn't three", "three");

    printf("\n%s\n", "These tests will be opposite in the C version\n");
    testLongestWord("the word antidisestablishmentarianism is very long but not as long as 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch'.", "Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch");
    testLongestWord("the word antidisestablishmentarianism is very long but not as long as 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch'.", "antidisestablishment");
    testLongestWord("Java strings may contain \0 in the interior", "interior");
    testLongestWord("C strings cannot contain \0 in the interior", "strings");

    printf("Total number of test executed:  %d\n", testsExecuted);
    printf("number of test passed:  %d\n", (testsExecuted - testsFailed));
    printf("Number of test failed: %d\n", testsFailed);

    // longestWord("Java strings may contain \0 in the interior");

}

// nextWord -- get next word
char *
nextWord(char *word,char *line)
{
    char *lhs;
    int c2;
    int alfcnt;
    int alf1;
    int alf2;
    int ch;

    //printf("nextWord: ENTER line='%s'\n",line);

    alfcnt = 0;
    lhs = word;

    for (ch = *line;  ch != 0;  ch = *++line) {
        alf1 = isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch);

        // store word chars
        if (alf1) {
            *lhs++ = ch;
            alfcnt = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (alfcnt) {
            c2 = line[1];
            alf2 = isalpha(c2) || isdigit(c2);

            if (alf2) {
                switch (ch) {
                case '\'': // store single quote [if it's part of a contraction]
                    *lhs++ = ch;
                    continue;
                    break;

                case '-': // store hyphen
                    *lhs++ = ch;
                    continue;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // didn't get a word char -- stop because we're at the end of a word
            break;
        }
    }

    *lhs = 0;

    if (! alfcnt)
        line = NULL;

    //printf("nextWord: EXIT lhs='%s' line='%s'\n",lhs,line);

    return line;
}

void
longestWord(char *longest,char *line)
{
    int longestLength = 0;
    char current[300];
    int currentLength = 0;
    char *cp;

    longest[0] = 0;

    while (1) {
        // get next word in line [we advance the line pointer for next round]
        line = nextWord(current,line);
        if (line == NULL)
            break;

        // get string length -- punctuation is _not_ counted in string length
        currentLength = 0;
        for (cp = current;  *cp != 0;  ++cp) {
            switch (*cp) {
            case '-':
            case '\'':
                break;
            default:
                currentLength += 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        // store longer word
        if (currentLength > longestLength) {
            strcpy(longest,current);
            longestLength = currentLength;
            continue;
        }

        if (currentLength < longestLength)
            continue;

        cp = strchr(longest,'-');
        if (cp == NULL)
            continue;

        cp = strchr(current,'-');
        if (cp != NULL)
            continue;

        // prefer non-dash over dash
        strcpy(longest,current);
    }
}

char
testLongestWord(char *line,char *expected)
{
    char result[2000];
    //char result = longestWords(line); // This is how it'd have been in Java

    longestWord(result,line);

    /* longestWord(line); */
    // strcpy(result, line);
    // char *result = longestWord(line);
    // printf("%s\n", line );
    // longestWord(&line)

    // function returns 0 if they are equal
    // NOTE/BUG: the sense of the if was wrong
    if (strcmp(result, expected) == 0) {
        printf("passed: '%s' from '%s'\n", result, line);
    }
    else {
        printf("FAILED: got '%s' from '%s' -- expected '%s'\n",
            result, line, expected);
        testsFailed++;
    }

    testsExecuted++;

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Per your request, belowed is a *fully* annotated version, explaining variable definitions and annotating the control flow.

As I was doing this, I realized that `nextWord` was computing [had knowledge] of things that `longestWord` had to recalculate, simply because `nextWord` had no way to convey this information.

So, I've added a `nextword` struct that allows `nextWord` to pass back *multiple* values. I don't know whether this is done in java, but it's fairly common in C.

The alternative to return multiple values is to do something like:

```
nextWord(blah,&var1,&var2,&var3,...);
```

This gets unwieldy quickly, so I decided to opt for the cleaner approach, even if it's slightly more difficult to understand at first.

Actually, another way to think of this is that `nextword` is like a [java] class, with a single method `nextWord`.  In that context, I'd probably reverse the order of the `nextWord` arguments (e.g. `nextWord(&rtn,current)`) as my convention in C is that the object instance pointer is the first argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

static int testsExecuted = 0;
static int testsFailed = 0;

char testLongestWord(char line[],char expected[]);

//void longestWord(char line[]);

int
main(int args,char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", "Testing typical cases, including punctuation\n");
    testLongestWord("the quick brown foxes jumped over the lazy dogs", "jumped");
    testLongestWord("hello world she said", "hello");
    testLongestWord("Hello\tworld\tshe\tsaid", "Hello");
    testLongestWord("HELLO, world she said", "HELLO");
    testLongestWord("hello world! she said???", "hello");
    testLongestWord("\"hello world!\", she said.", "hello");
    testLongestWord("easy as abc123", "abc123");
    testLongestWord("easy as abc,123", "easy");

    printf("\n%s\n", "Testing empty cases\n");
    testLongestWord("", "");
    testLongestWord("!", "");
    testLongestWord(" ", "");
    testLongestWord("\t", "");
    testLongestWord("      ", "");
    testLongestWord("# $ ? % !", "");

    printf("\n%s\n", "Testing edge cases\n");
    testLongestWord("a", "a");
    testLongestWord("abc", "abc");
    testLongestWord("abc d e f ghi", "abc");
    testLongestWord("a a b cc dd abc", "abc");
    testLongestWord("\"a a b cc dd abc.\"", "abc");

    printf("\n%s\n", "Testing apostrophes and dashes\n");
    testLongestWord("this isn't five chars", "chars");
    testLongestWord("this should've been eight chars said the computer", "should've");
    testLongestWord("'this should've been eight chars', said the computer", "should've");
    testLongestWord("'hello world!', she said softly.", "softly");
    testLongestWord("topsy-turvy is a tenletter word", "topsy-turvy");
    testLongestWord("topsy-turvy should not be incorrectly eleven characters", "incorrectly");
    testLongestWord("---in-between-these---", "in-between-these");
    testLongestWord("---in---between---these---", "between");
    testLongestWord("here-is-an-edge-case but a muchmuchlongerword", "muchmuchlongerword");
    testLongestWord("d-o-n't-g-o-o-v-e-r-t-h-e-e-d-g-e with muchmuchlongerwords", "muchmuchlongerwords");
    testLongestWord("two=five-3 isn't three", "three");

    printf("\n%s\n", "These tests will be opposite in the C version\n");
    testLongestWord("the word antidisestablishmentarianism is very long but not as long as 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch'.", "Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch");
    testLongestWord("the word antidisestablishmentarianism is very long but not as long as 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch'.", "antidisestablishment");
    testLongestWord("Java strings may contain \0 in the interior", "interior");
    testLongestWord("C strings cannot contain \0 in the interior", "strings");

    printf("Total number of test executed:  %d\n", testsExecuted);
    printf("number of test passed:  %d\n", (testsExecuted - testsFailed));
    printf("Number of test failed: %d\n", testsFailed);

    // longestWord("Java strings may contain \0 in the interior");

}

// nextWord state control ("helper")
// NOTE: we use this sort of struct when we must maintain/update _multiple_
// variables across a function call [or calls]
struct nextword {
    char *line;                         // current line position [updated]
    int alfcnt;                         // alphanumeric length
    int hypflg;                         // 1=word is hyphenated
};

// nextWord -- get next word
void
nextWord(char *word,struct nextword *rtn)
// word -- pointer to place to store extracted word
// rtn -- pointer to our state control and values we return
{
    char *line;  // pointer to sentence/phrase to extract words from
    char *wp;  // current position in word
    int ch;  // current character
    int c2;  // next character [lookahead if needed]
    int alf1;  // 1=current char is alphanumeric
    int alf2;  // 1=next char is alphanumeric
    int alfcnt;  // number of alphanumeric characters

    // printf("nextWord: ENTER line='%s'\n",line);

    // say no alpha chars and "not hyphenated"
    alfcnt = 0;
    rtn->hypflg = 0;

    // set the word "creeper" [current position for destination]
    // NOTES:
    // (1) using a separate "wp" in unnecessary as we don't need to retain the
    //     original word value (i.e. below we could just do "word" in place of
    //     "wp")
    // (2) in the previous version, this was called "lhs" [which, as you
    //     surmised, meant "left hand side"]
    // (3) in my style, this might also be called "dst" [for destination]
    wp = word;

    // get "source" pointer
    // NOTES:
    // (1) in my style, this could also be named "rhs" ["right hand side"]
    // (2) another style would be "src" for "source" if we used "dst" above
    line = rtn->line;

    for (ch = *line;  ch != 0;  ch = *++line) {
        // is current char alphanumeric?
        alf1 = isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch);

        // store word chars
        // NOTE: only these characters are considered for our purposes of
        // "string" length
        if (alf1) {
            *wp++ = ch;
            alfcnt += 1;
            continue;
        }

        // iff we've started a word, we consider internal punctuation and
        // hyphenation
        if (alfcnt) {
            // peek at _next_ character in line
            c2 = line[1];
            alf2 = isalpha(c2) || isdigit(c2);

            // consider special characters if _next_ character is alpha
            if (alf2) {
                switch (ch) {
                case '\'':  // store quote [if it's part of a contraction]
                    *wp++ = ch;
                    continue;
                    break;

                case '-':  // store hyphen
                    *wp++ = ch;
                    rtn->hypflg = 1;  // remember that word is hyphenated
                    continue;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // didn't get a word char -- stop because we're at the end of a word
            break;
        }

        // wait for start of a word (i.e. alphanumeric)
    }

    // finish off the extracted word
    *wp = 0;

    // if we didn't find any word chars, tell caller to stop
    if (! alfcnt)
        line = NULL;

    // return multiple values to caller
    // NOTE: we already updated hypflg above [if necessary]
    rtn->alfcnt = alfcnt;
    rtn->line = line;

    // printf("nextWord: EXIT lhs='%s' line='%s'\n",lhs,line);
}

// longestWord -- find longest word in a line
void
longestWord(char *longest,char *line)
// longest -- pointer to buffer where we return the longest extracted word
// line -- pointer to string that has the phrase to extract words from
{
    int longlen = 0;  // length of longest string so far
    int longhyp = 0;  // 1=longest word is hyphenated
    char current[300];  // current word being considered
    int curlen;
    struct nextword rtn;  // control struct to allow nextWord to update state

    // handle empty strings
    longest[0] = 0;

    // initialize this once -- nextWord will update it
    rtn.line = line;

    while (1) {
        // get next word in line [we advance the line pointer for next round]
        nextWord(current,&rtn);

        // no more words found
        if (rtn.line == NULL)
            break;

        // nextWord has already computed the length for us
        curlen = rtn.alfcnt;

        // store longer word [remembering its length and whether it's
        // hyphenated or not]
        if (curlen > longlen) {
            strcpy(longest,current);
            longlen = curlen;
            longhyp = rtn.hypflg;
            continue;
        }

        // skip shorter words than what we already have
        if (curlen < longlen)
            continue;

        // decide if longest is hyphenated -- ignore if not
        if (! longhyp)
            continue;

        // decide if current is hyphenated -- ignore if so (i.e. it's no better)
        if (rtn.hypflg)
            continue;

        // prefer non-dash over dash
        strcpy(longest,current);
        longhyp = rtn.hypflg;
    }
}

char
testLongestWord(char *line,char *expected)
{
    char result[2000];

    // char result = longestWords(line); // This is how it'd have been in Java

    longestWord(result,line);

    /* longestWord(line); */
    // strcpy(result,line);
    // char *result = longestWord(line);
    // printf("%s\n",line );
    // longestWord(&line)

    // function returns 0 if they are equal
    // NOTE/BUG: the sense of the if was wrong
    if (strcmp(result,expected) == 0) {
        printf("passed: '%s' from '%s'\n",result,line);
    }
    else {
        printf("FAILED: got '%s' from '%s' -- expected '%s'\n",
            result,line,expected);
        testsFailed++;
    }

    testsExecuted++;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for putting comments on them, i tried to run it but it doesn't give out the correct output. I edited to include the output

Comment: Okay. I had oversimplified some things. I've just posted the corrected code which now matches your java results [AFAICT]

Comment: thank you! do you mind commenting what the variables do(their names) ? especially the lhs, alfcnt,alf1...?i'm trying to understand what it's doing and i'm thinking left hand side but not sure

Answer (score 1):

To copy `char [] line` which is not *dynamically allocated*

```
char * result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(line));
strcpy(result, line);
```

In case of dynamically allocated, you need to keep the size of the array, since `sizeof` doesn't work with dynamically allocated arrays. In general you could do something like this

```
struct String
{
    char * c;
    size_t size;
};

String* str(char* in, size_t size)
{
    String* out = (String*)malloc(sizeof(String));
    out->c = 0;
    out->size = size;

    if (size) out->c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

    if (input) memcpy(out->c, in, size);
    else out->c[0] = '\0';

    return out;
}

int main (void)
{
    // t is static string
    char t[255] = "Test";

    // a is dynamic string; copy of t
    String* a = str(t, sizeof(t));

    // b is dynamic string; empty string with size of a
    String* b = str(0, a->size);

    // copy b into a
    memcpy(b->c, a->c);

    return 0;
}
```