# A char pointer function returns string inside the function but not in main?

Tags: c, pointers, char

Why does the value of t in stringParser prints "Hello" but not in main function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* stringParser(char st[]) {
    char temp[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (st[i] != '\0') {
        temp[i] = st[i];
        i++;
    }
    temp[i] = '\0';
    char* t = temp;
    printf("%s", t);  
    return t;                // Outputs: "Hello"
}

int main() {
    char y[] = "Hello"; 
    printf("\n%s", stringParser(y));   //Outputs: "╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠⌠²Ö"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @neostar After exiting the function the returned pointer is invalid because the pointed array that is a local variable of the function with the automatic storage duration is not alive.

Comment: @Carcigenicate t is a pointer pointing to string temp so the function stringParser() should return that pointer. Shouldn't the pointer from stringParser hold the value of string temp?

Comment: Look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fE9Pez) then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Comment: @neostar all local variables inside a function are destroyed once the function calls ends, here the variable  temp is destroyed so your function returns a pointer which point to temp address but the value of temp has been destroyed

Comment: Maybe duplicate of *[Returning string from C function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25798977/4415884)*?

Comment: @neostar `t` holds only a pointer to the array `temp`, the array `temp` is not copied. If the array `temp` does not exist anymore and you try to dereference the pointer `t` ( or a copy of the pointer, by returning the pointer) you cause UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `temp` exist only in the scope of function `stringParser()`. The pointer `t` points to the array `temp` or in other words `t` holds the address of where `temp` is stored. When you return from the function `stringParser()`, the array `temp` does no longer exist and accessing it causes undefined behavior (UB). You return the pointer `t` that points to `temp` and give it to `printf()`. `printf()` dereferences the pointer, means it wants to access the array to which `t` points to, but the array `temp` does no long exist and therefore you have UB.

There are multiple ways to avoid UB:

- Make the array `temp` `static`. But that does not work well with multi threading programs and should be avoided in libraries.
- Use dynamic memory allocation, reserve the storage for the `temp`-array with `malloc()` or `calloc()`, but then you have to `free()` the memory again after you no longer need it.
- Declare the array inside `main()` and pass a pointer to it to `stringParser()`, but keep the size in check and make sure you never get a buffer overflow.

Off-Topic: `size_t` is a better type for array indexing, since it is guaranteed to be large enough to hold every possible index and `size_t` is unsigned. Your program is prone to buffer overflows by future changes. Since you do not document that the string given to `stringParser()` has to be shorter than 100 `char`s. You need to document that better, check if the string is not too long or create the array dynamically to be big enough for the given string.