# error: address of stack memory associated with local variable

Tags: c, variables, char, stack, cs50

I have the following function:

```
string encipher(string plaintext, string key) {
    int size = strlen(plaintext);
    char ciphertext[size];
    // For each alphabetic characters determine what letter it map to
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; k[j] != plaintext[i]; j++) {
               ciphertext[i] = key[j];
           }
    }
    return ciphertext;
}
```

Unfortunately when I compile it returns me the following error:

> error: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'ciphertext' returned [-Werror,-Wreturn-stack-address] return ciphertext; ^~~~~~~~~~

I tried `static` and `malloc` but I am not sure to understand how the stack allocation works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning string from C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798977/returning-string-from-c-function)

Comment: is this a CS50 question?

Comment: Where does `string` come from?

Comment: @M.M yes, it's pset2/substitution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in C are passed by reference, and you do not return the array only pointer to it.

```
char ciphertext[size];
```

is a local automatic variable which ceases to exist when the function returns - thus any reference to it is invalid.

What to do? You need to dynamically allocate the string:

```
string encipher(string plaintext, string key)
{
    int size = strlen(plaintext);
    char *ciphertext = malloc(size);
    // check for allocation errors
    // remember to free this memory when not needed
    // For each alphabetic characters determine what letter it map to
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
           for(int j = 0; k[j] != plaintext[i]; j++)
           {
               ciphertext[i] = key[j];
           }
    }
    return ciphertext;
}
```

or buffer should be allocated by the caller

```
string encipher(char *ciphertext, string plaintext, string key)
{
    int size = strlen(plaintext);
    // For each alphabetic charaters determine what letter it map to
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
           for(int j = 0; k[j] != plaintext[i]; j++)
           {
               ciphertext[i] = key[j];
           }
    }
    return ciphertext;
}
```

BTW hiding pointers behind typedefs is a very bad practice.

Comment: Where do you see pointers hiding behind typedefs?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The CS50 course's provided library provides such a typedef. IMHO the remark is somewhat relevant, but not actionable by the OP

Comment: @RobertHarvey for example `string`. I did not mention that OP has hired it,

Comment: @0___________ Using ```malloc``` as per your answer returns the following 

error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
    char ciphertext = malloc(size);
         ^            ~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @MarcoM typo. See amended, BTW you see what is wrong from the messgae.