# Is it safe returning Arduino String from a C function?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

In software provided for multiple system on a chip microcontrollers I discovered this piece of code

```cpp
String getMacAddress() {
  uint8_t baseMac[6];
  char baseMacChr[13] = {0};
#  if defined(ESP8266)
  WiFi.macAddress(baseMac);
  sprintf(baseMacChr, "%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X", baseMac[0], baseMac[1], baseMac[2], baseMac[3], baseMac[4], baseMac[5]);
#  elif defined(ESP32)
  esp_read_mac(baseMac, ESP_MAC_WIFI_STA);
  sprintf(baseMacChr, "%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X", baseMac[0], baseMac[1], baseMac[2], baseMac[3], baseMac[4], baseMac[5]);
#  else
  sprintf(baseMacChr, "%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X", mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
#  endif
  return String(baseMacChr);
}
```

Where `String` is provided by Arduino context. So on those microcontroller is this piece of code safe?

I know that there is a problem with the scope/longevity of the returned variable (well explained here: [Returning a C string from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496313/returning-a-c-string-from-a-function) ) which most people get around with the `std::string` but I don't have any experience in the context of microcontrollers, and since I've seen it used a lot, I've come up with this question.

I haven't found any documentation about it, every bit of extra information is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it safe returning Arduino String

Yes. `String` manages it's memory.

> from a C function?

Well, it's not a "C function", it's a normal function in C++.

> which most people get around with the std::string but I don't have any experience in the context of microcontrollers

It does not differ that much, and you can also use `std::string` on esp.

`String` and other similar interfaces from Arduino are there to save memory (use `realloc`, instead of `delete+new` on resize) and to interface with Arduino specific stuff easier (constructor with `__FlashStringHelper`). It's meant to "mimic" `std::string` with some Arduino or embedded specific behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The String class in arduino does not store a pointer to a character but *copies* it into its internal memory.

The copy constructor takes care of the rest when returning String from a function.

So yes, it's safe

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me since you are allocating the strings with automatic storage duration in the caller to the function.

Check they are of sufficient size though - you need to consult the function documentation for that.

With `return String(baseMacChr);`, `baseMacChr` does not go out of scope conceptually until the closing `}` of the function `getMacAddress`, so that too is safe.

If you can use `std::string` rather than `String` then it would be even better. Every C++ programmer knows exactly what the former is. Using `String` (whatever that is) can only add to confusion.