# returning an array of char from a function to a variable in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm learning C but got some problem when I want to return a string from a function to the main. This is a part of the code (I know it is completely wrong but I can't figure out how to make it do what I want)

I understand that the return value (*name) only returns the location of the first char of the string and pass it to the main.

```
int main(void)
{
    char name[100] = {get_name("Name: ")};
    printf("%s\n", name);
}

char get_name(char prompt[])
{
    printf("%s", prompt);
    char name[100];
    scanf("%s", name);
    return *name;
}
```

I think it is not possible to return the whole string to the main function, that's why I went with the pointer; however I cannot get the whole string anymore. I even checked the length of the array in the main, it shows 100, but there exist only one character in it and name[1] is empty.

Can someone please explain to me why it behaves like this and how to fix it? I searched everywhere but couldn't find a clue.

Comment: You can't return an array by value in C.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a C string from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496313/returning-a-c-string-from-a-function)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Returning string from C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798977/returning-string-from-c-function)

Comment: So, what do you think `char name[100] = {some-char};` does?

Answer (score 1):

> returning an array of char from a function to a variable in C
> when I want to return a string from a function

In C, an array **cannot be returned**.  A pointer to an array can be returned.

In C, a string **cannot be returned**.  A pointer  to a *string* can be returned.

Comment: This question already has multiple duplicates.  You may want to vote to close it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to accomplish what you want -- code is updated per the following:

1.) name array is declared static in get_name().

"When a variable is declared as static, memory is allocated for the
lifetime of the program. Even if the function is called multiple times,
space for the static variable is allocated only once and the value of
the variable in the previous call gets carried through the next
function call."  credit: [www.geeksforgeeks.org](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org)

... hence, the "static" keyword allows us to return the name string to main()

2.) get_name() is updated to return a char pointer.  Now it can return a pointer to name array.

Please see my "updated" comments added to your code for each change.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/rKM5Yq9jY) is runnable code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *get_name(char prompt[])  /* Updated:  returns char pointer */
{
    static char name[100]="Billy";  /* Updated:  static key word */
    printf("%s", prompt);
    scanf("%s", name);
    return name;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *name = get_name("Name: ");  /* Updated: name variable is a pointer now */
    printf("%s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is another solution inspired by user @Gerhardh.  It uses dynamically allocated memory.  Please check into it when you are ready to take your skills to the next level.  Dynamic memory allocation is a critical skill for any coder.   Runnable code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4W8cqfb7e):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *get_name(char prompt[])  /* Updated:  returns char pointer */
{
    char *name= malloc(100);  /* Updated: uses memory allocation. */
    if(name)  /* Was memory allocation a success? */
    {
        /* Answer: yes... we can proceed to use that memory: */
        printf("%s", prompt);
        scanf("%s", name);
    }
    return name;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *name = get_name("Name: ");  /* Updated: name variable is a pointer now */
    if(name)  /* Was memory allocation a success? */
    {
        printf("%s\n", name);
        free(name); /* Free the allocated memory when you are done with it */
    }
    else
        printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and I think I got how to do it. gotta play with it a little bit more.

Comment: @Noori Muhammed -- very welcome and best wishes.  Thank you for your feedback; it always means a lot to me to know I helped a little.

Comment: You migh add that you cannot use that function to read 2 different strings. As the same buffer is used in every function call, all variables holding a pointer returned from that function will point to the same string.

Comment: @Gerhardh -- spot on!  Yes, there some hazards with the given approach.  I personally prefer a solution that calls malloc() with each call to get_name(), and then the caller will take responsibility to free() that memory returned by get_name().  But I'm sensing our caller is new, and so I'm presenting the very simplest solution that looks most like his original code.  Well, you've inspired me to add another method... thank you!

Comment: "But I'm sensing our caller is new," That is also my view. One more reason not to send them in a direction where the next trap is just waiting for them to fall into.

Comment: This question already has multiple duplicates.  You may want to vote to close it instead. Using the `static` keyword,  using `malloc()`, and other methods have been explained in detail in other questions already. If there is anything unique, you may consider adding it to the previous questions instead. _Otherwise, you're only making it harder for site maintainers to close duplicate questions._

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa -- oh!  OK, understood and agreed.  thx.  I am desisting -- but I don't think i have close-voting power yet. I'll poke around a little bit more to see....